# Oracle managed driver can't resolve TNS name, yet exists in trace

Tags: c#, odp.net-managed

I've installed and configured the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess client with the correct TNS_ADMIN setting (in .NET config file).  When I enable Oracle tracing, it correctly picks up the TNS_ADMIN setting and even lists all of the TNS entries from TNSNAMES.ORA.  The TNS name that I'm using in my connection string exists in the trace output.

However, when I try to connect using the TNS name in my connection string (in the 'Data Source=...;' section), it still gives me ORA-12154 (can't resolve connect identifier).  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... the Oracle managed provider identifies the connect identifier in the trace.  I'm also able to TNSPING the connect identifier with any issue, and my Oracle managed config is pointed to the same TNSNAMES.ORA used by TNSPING.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, show `app.config` file

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to put the TNS configuration directly in the connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xe)));User Id=...;Password=...;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however I work in an enterprise and we don't want that connection information duplicated.